# Equivalent of c++ include in R

Tags: r

I have 3 scripts `logs.R`, `func.R`, `main.R` and I want to log from `main` and also from `func` scripts. I know that I can use `source`, for having the functions in both scripts, but sourcing `logs` in `func` and in `main`, is the same of sourcing it 2 times (I source `func` in `main`). Is there any equivalent of `#pragma once` or `#ifndef #define #endif` from `C++` ?

Comment: Have you considered putting `func` in a single place, and importing it to the other scripts, avoiding the problem entirely?

Comment: No, I do not want a huge script that nobody can read

Comment: Voted for reopen: as the two answers show, it has a clear answer, not "too many possible answers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mimic that with a custom variable and a condition.

logs.R

```
...
log.sourced <- TRUE
```

func.R

```
if(!exists("log.sourced")) source("logs.R")
...
```

main.R

```
if(!exists("log.sourced")) source("logs.R")
...
```

Or just test `exists("func")` where `func` is defined in logs.R

Comment: +1. Just the logic way as `#ifdef` / `#ifndef` / `#define` are compiler specific (and their need is specific too), mimicking the behavior sounds the best way.

Answer (score 1):

use the [`source("otherfile.R")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/source.html) to include the content of other files. (equivalent of include).

As R is directly interpreted and no preprocessed, there is not equivalent of `#pragma once` or **include guards** directive.

One way to replace the **include guards** would be to write in directly in R.

Comment: So you are saying that sourcing more times the same script is not going to be bad?

Comment: The script is reinterpreted as many ttime as you include it, so it could be bad from a performance point of view. you could of course write your onwn version of `source_once`

Comment: But there is nothing preventing from re-assigning function multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Since there’s no proper solution in base R and other solutions require on hacky mechanisms like include guards, I wrote my own package: ‘[**box**](https://klmr.me/box/)’.

With modules you can for instance write the following code:

```
box::use(./logs)
```

And now you can use `logs` like a package/namespace you’re used to in other languages: `logs$log('Some string I’d like to log.')`. Or, alternatively, you could do

```
box::use(./logs[...])
```

This mimics R’s normal attaching mechanism, and is similar to `using namespace foo` in C++. See the [‘box’ vignette](https://klmr.me/box/articles/box.html) for a more in-depth introduction.